# Instantiate constructor class with mysqli with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Im calling a class to connect to my local mySql database via a constructor method. Im getting a 500 error when i start the php file. Is there somthing I'm doing wrong? Im passing the values of the host user pass and dbName into the class when i instantiate it but cannot connect. The db is working fine as I have tested it.

```php
<?php

Class MyDB{

    public $query;
    public $myConnection;

    public function__construct($host, $username, $password, $dbname){

        $this->myConnection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

    }

    public function listScores(){

        $this->query = "SELECT answer FROM correct_guesses" or die("error ..." . mysqli_error($this->$myConnection));

        $result = $this->$myConnection->query($this->query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row["answer"] . "<br>";

        }
    }
}

$score = new MyDB('localhost','root','root','scoreDB');

$score->listScores();

?>
```

Comment: Well there's a space missing here: `function__construct` but I'm not sure that should cause an HTTP 500 error.

Comment: A generic 500 error means you need to check your server logs.  It's best to develop using a server that reports/displays all errors instead of logging them.

Comment: Your query is going to fail as well. That's not how you add a die statement to the query.

Comment: How can `$this->query` ever fail to assign a value? There's a lot going wrong here on a number of levels, but most of all you're mixing the OO-style and the procedural style. Use the OO-style.

Comment: Hi Aynber, It worked fine for me after i appended the missing white space and $ on myConnection on line 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "public function__construct() has no white space in it. It must be like below:

```
public function __construct()
```

It will definitely give you 500 error.

[image]

Comment: I have text-editor that gives php error. You can also enable all errors and warnings on on server side for debugging. (on dev only)

Answer (score 0):

﻿Not sure if it is the cause but $this->$myConnection should be $this->myConnection. That's on the second line of the listScores method

Comment: After the white space was missing from the constructor method this was also an issue thank you fergal

Comment: Glad to help Callum